# Why does pandas.DatetimeTZDtype compare equal to numpy.dtype("O")? Is this expected?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was surprised to find that `pandas.DatetimeTZDtype` compares equal to `numpy.dtype("O")`:

```
>>> numpy.dtype("O") == pandas.DatetimeTZDtype
True
```

I ran into this in a unit test, where a test was unexpectedly passing.

Is this equality expected, or should it be considered a bug?  I couldn't find it documented in the [`DatetimeTZDtype` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeTZDtype.html), nor could I find it described in an issue in either pandas or numpy; but it might be a side-effect of some (historical) design consideration.

Comment: Of what I understand, pandas data types are extension of numpy data types. Any data type (like DatetimeTZDtype, [see this list for more example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=basics#dtypes)) that does not exist in numpy are then "associated" to object numpy type. So not a bug, more a design solution I guess

Answer (score 2):

Checking the docs:

```
pd.DatetimeTZDtype(
    unit: Union[str, ForwardRef('DatetimeTZDtype')] = 'ns',
    tz=None,
)
Docstring:     
An ExtensionDtype for timezone-aware datetime data.

**This is not an actual numpy dtype**, but a duck type.
```

and the class inheritance is entirely different:

```
In [162]: type(np.dtype('O')).__mro__
Out[162]: (numpy.dtype[object_], numpy.dtype, object)
In [163]: pd.DatetimeTZDtype.__mro__
Out[163]: 
(pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype,
 pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.PandasExtensionDtype,
 pandas.core.dtypes.base.ExtensionDtype,
 object)
```

I'm not sure where the `==` test is defined.  For `numpy`, object dtype is a catch all, everything that is not a defined dtype (numeric, string, etc).

```
In [186]: np.dtype('O').__eq__(pd.core.dtypes.base.ExtensionDtype)
Out[186]: True
```

So following `DatetimeTSDtype` docs, make:

```
In [202]: dt = pd.DatetimeTZDtype(tz='UTC')
```

With that I can make a Series:

```
In [203]: S = pd.Series(["2020-10-01"],dtype=dt)
In [204]: S
Out[204]: 
0   2020-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

but when I ask for the `numpy` equivalent:

```
In [205]: S.to_numpy()
Out[205]: array([Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')], dtype=object)
```

I cannot make an array with `dt`:

```
In [206]: np.array("2020-10-01",dtype=dt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-206-c3b73b03da08>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array("2020-10-01",dtype=dt)
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'datetime64[ns, UTC]' as a data type
```